# How to create a multidimensional array with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that includes images and orders;

```
 foreach ($images as $image){
   $results => [
            'url' => $image["url"]
            'order' => $image["order"]
        ]
    }
```

This only gets the first image and order.
I need to get all the images and orders and execute excute each entry like ;

```
 Array
  (
       [attribute] => [
           [url] => "foo"
           [order] => "boo"
       ]

       [attribute] => [
           [url] => "foo"
           [order] => "boo"
       ]
  )

    //... etc
   
    
    'images' => [
         $results; // need to use the $results array in another array like this
     ]
```

thanks for help.

Comment: Are you stuck with syntax of it?

Comment: @nice_dev not really, I edited my question and tried to explain clearly

Comment: Your current code snippet isn't executable. I am suspecting you are missing a `[]` collect syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$results = [];
 foreach ($images as $image){
   $results['attribute'][] = [
        'url' => $image["url"],
        'order' => $image["order"]
    ];
 }
 print_r($results);
```

Comment: Tried this, but i need to put "url" and "order" into "attribute" array.

Comment: @RecepŞimşek pls try now for attribute array

Comment: [attribute] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array // can ignore this line?
                (
                    [url] => example.jpg
                    [order] => 0
                )

        )

Comment: Nope. If you want to remove then you will get the last items only as it will replace all values with previous one due to having same index 'attribute'